# How To Bind A DataTable To Multiple Chart Series

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, charts, mschart

I am using VS 2015 and I want to display a data table I have created as a chart.

The data table looks like this.

[image: Data table view]

I havent really used charts before and I have tried a few examples/tutorials found online but I am not getting anywhere.

I would like a line chart with the x axis as timestamp, y as value and 3 lines (in this example) for each tag name.

I have added the control to the page using

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

This is what I have in my VB so far but I am aware it probably doesnt contain enough/correct information for the chart to display.

```
With Chart1.Series(0)

    .Points.DataBind(trendTagData, "timestamp", "Value", Nothing)

End With
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB is really not my thing, but this is a *one-liner*:

```
    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dt.DefaultView, "tagname", "timestamp", "value", "");
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You may also need to do this, AFTER you call `DataBindCrossTable`, in order to get a `Line` chart type:

```
        Chart1.Series["tag1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart1.Series["tag2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart1.Series["tag3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

OR

if you don't know how many tag names are in your table, do this:

```
        foreach (Series s in Chart1.Series)
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Also, note you can remove `Series1` from your ASPX markup.

Comment: That works but I get a bar chart even if I specify chart type as line in the asp??

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: excellent thank for taking the time to provide this information

Comment: `For Each s As Series In Chart1.Series`. Just providing the VB syntax.